# partitioning intervals by distance

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I've got a table in a Redshift database that contains intervals with lower bounds `l` and upper bounds `u`, like so:

```
| interval_id | l  | u  |
| ----------- | -- | -- |
| 1           | 1  | 10 |
| 2           | 2  | 5  |
| 3           | 5  | 15 |
| 4           | 26 | 30 |
| 5           | 28 | 35 |
| 6           | 30 | 31 |
| 7           | 44 | 45 |
| 8           | 56 | 58 |
```

I would like to partition these intervals such that the sets are at least 10 apart. The desired result for the example above would be

```
| interval_id | l  | u  | group |
| ----------- | -- | -- | ----- |
| 1           | 1  | 10 | A     |
| 2           | 2  | 5  | A     |
| 3           | 5  | 15 | A     |
| 4           | 26 | 30 | B     |
| 5           | 28 | 35 | B     |
| 6           | 30 | 31 | B     |
| 7           | 44 | 45 | B     |
| 8           | 56 | 58 | C     |
```

where e.g. the first three rows would belong to group `a` because these intervals either overlap or outright contain each other or are less than 10 apart and row 4 belongs to group `b` because its lower bound is `11` away from the upper bound of the union (well, technically the convex hull) of intervals 1-3.

Comment: Your logic isnt clear. Because one range can overlap with two groups.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I want the groups to be such that that's not the case.

Comment: Again you need to explain that with more detail. overlap is easy to determinate. But `outright contain each other` isnt. Who contain who? what mean 10 apart, how calculate? What about `18,25` will be group `A` or `B`?

Comment: I want the group assignments to depend on the intervals in the set. If you added `[18,25]` to the set of intervals then intervals 1-7 and `[18,25]` would all belong to the same group (because within that set of intervals there is no gap of more than 10) and only interval 8 would be in a group of its own.

Comment: So you need to create groups in the same order by `interval_id`? How you measure the gap?

Comment: Yeah, but that only works in this case because `interval_id`s are in the same order as l and the difference between `l` und `u` is always less than or equal to 10.

Comment: Then explain a better case, because I was about to use the order of interval_id to solve the problem.

Comment: Here's a full description of an algorithm that would give me the group assignments I want: (1) start with an interval, (2) go through the other intervals. If for any of these intervals there is overlap with the original interval or if there is a gap of less than 10 between the two intervals, assign it to the same group, (3) take the convex hull of the intervals in the group, repeat (2), once there are no more intervals that can be assigned to the group, take an unassigned interval and start again at (1).

I'm not sure that's the best algorithm and I'm not sure how this would work in SQL.

Comment: While your exact purpose is unclear, check out analytical window functions in redshift: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_synopsis.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm.  I think you can take the max of the upper bound for all preceding rows to see where a break occurs.  Then, the rest is just a cumulative sum:

```
select u.*,
       sum(case when l < prev_max_u + 10 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by l) as groupid
from (select t.*,
             max(u) over (order by l rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  as prev_max_u
      from t
     ) u;
```

I would normally approach this using a correlated subquery, but I think this formulation will work.  I might not work if you have two rows that are exact duplicates.

Comment: I don't think this will work as expected if one interval is contained in another

Comment: You need also consider `l`, because `{1,10}` and `{10,25}` should be on the same group

Comment: Almost. Replacing `sum(case when u < prev_max_u + 10 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by l) as groupid` with `sum(case when l < prev_max_u + 10 then 0 else 1 end) over (order by l rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as groupid` does the trick, I think